# Web Api HTTPPost not accepting int

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, postman, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to just pass in `body` a `int` and it does not work
Why do I need to create a class with a property of type int ?   (then it works)

**WORKS**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/UpdateMainReversed")]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateMainVerified(DataAccess.Entities.RequestMain mainValues)
    {  ....}
```

**DO NOT WORK**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/UpdateMainReversed")]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateMainVerified(int mainId)
    {  ....}
```

Testing with Postman

http://localhost:13497/api/UpdateMainReversed

Body

```
{
   "mainId" : 1615
}
```

Comment: You want to pass int in body or url?

Comment: body,  because its POST and not supposed to pass in URL for proper REST

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1.Your [HttpPost] expects a int but from body you are passing a json object. you should pass json string like below. No need to mention parameter name

[image]

2.you should use [FromBody] as below

```
[HttpPost]
    public void UpdateMainVerified([FromBody] int mainid)
    {

    }
```

this link explains it well

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: NICE JOB.    I read several articles and was ready to give up as I could pass in a string instead of int  to string mainid ... but value was null.    THIS solution actually works!   thx

Comment: Also if using axios, post data as axios.post('/UpdateMainVerified', mainId) not as json i.e. axios.post('/UpdateMainVerified', {mainId: mainId})

Answer (score 3):

Set `FromBody` Attribute.

> To force Web API to read a simple type from the request body, add the `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameter.

For details [Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding/)

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/UpdateMainReversed")]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateMainVerified([FromBody] int mainId)
    {  ....}
```

Comment: {
  "message": "The request is invalid.",
  "messageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'mainId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult AddProduct(Int32)' i

Comment: set Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: then it would no longer be JSON Muhammad ... I'm in your situation user6321478 , if anyone has a fix